# WebGet and object as GET parameter in WCF REST client

Tags: wcf, rest

Let's say we have REST client with next declaration:

```
[ServiceContract]
interface ITestClient
{
    [OperationContract]
    [WebGet(UriTemplate = "SetData/?d1={d1}&d2={d2}")]
    void SetData(string d1, string d2);
}
```

I would like tu use it with next signature (HTTP GET):

```
[ServiceContract]
interface ITestClient
{
    [OperationContract]
    [WebGet(UriTemplate = "SetData/?")]
    void SetData(SetDataRequest setData);
}

[DataContract]
public class SetDataRequest
{
    [DataMember(Name = "d1")]
    private string Data1 { get; set; }

    [DataMember(Name = "d2")]
    private string Data2 { get; set; }
}
```

I wish that WCF serializes instance of the `SetDataRequest` to HTTP QueryString.
Is this possible (HTTP POST is not acceptable)?

Answer (score 0):

You should not use WebGet for this you should instead do:-

```
[OperationContract]
[WebInvoke( UriTemplate="SetDate/" Method="POST")]
void SetData(SetDataRequest setData);
```

You should use a post when submitting data as you will run into security/caching issues if you don't.

Comment: I don't have access to server side of the service so I'm bound to HTTP GET. HTTP POST is not an option in this case. Security is solved by https protocol binding.

Comment: tbh its probably easier to have a helper object that just serializes it to string.

Comment: oh, and security isn't resolved by https, caching is as a side effect! People can still do cross site request forgery attacks on the service.